# Has this system of equations a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be an inner product space, let $v\in X$, $a\in \mathbb R$.

Let us consider the system of equations:

$\|x\|=1, \langle x,v \rangle=a.$

If it has a solution, then by the Schwarz inequality $|a| \leq \|v\|$.
Is it true the converse, if $|a| \leq \|v\|$, then that sysem has a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by converse? Would it state: let $a \in R$ and $v \in X$ such that $|a| \leq ||v||$. Then there exists $x \in X$ such that $||x|| = 1$ and $x \cdot v = a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it always has. Let $H$ be the orthogonal hyperplane to $\mathbb{R}v$. Decompose $x = x_1+\lambda v$ with $x_1\in H$. Then, $\left<x,v \right>=a$ imposes $\lambda =\frac{a}{\|v\|^2}$. With this choice of $\lambda$, we have 
$$\|x\|^2 = \frac{a^2}{ \|v\|^2}+ \|x_1\|^2.$$
To conclude, it suffices to choose $x_1 \in H$ of norm $\sqrt{1- \frac{a^2}{ \|v\|^2}}$.

Edit : Special cases :

- if $v=0$, then $a=0$ and there is still a solution.
- If $H$ = {0}, e.g. $X=\mathbb{R}v$, then there is not a solution if $|a| < \|v\|$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no (extreme apologies if I'm wrong!). The problem is if $dim(X)=1$ and $v \neq 0$ such that $|a|<||v||$